# ACTION_AIRPLAN_MODE_CHANGED will never be called

Tags: android

I have a receiver in which I want to react if the users changed to airplane mode, but currently this will never be called in my application. The other ACTION_STATE_CHANGE will be received in my code. Any idea?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private de.srs.android.pdixuploader.util.Settings penSettings;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)){
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    stopSDK();
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    startSDK( new de.srs.android.pdixuploader.util.Settings(false, false));
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)){
            Log.d(TAG, "airplane mode changed");
        }

    }
};
```

The receiver will be registered in the onCreate Method of my service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appData = (AttachApplication) getApplication();     
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(btReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: How did you register this receiver?? Add that code here

Comment: I added the code above

Comment: Actually I receive an intent if the airplane mode has been turned on but if turning the airplane mode off again will not push an ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED event. So I can not react if the mode has been turned off